# Android animation Progress callback method

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, asynchronous

I want to know that like jQuery is there is an option to check the remaining time of animation in android of any control. Like to check how much milliseconds are remaining to complete the animation. In specific words the listener that runs between start and end of animation that is currently running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found the answer by my self. As I want to use this functionality to increase time on fix time passes or remaining time left by the animation so I have found this

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class HeightAnimation extends Animation {
    protected final int originalHeight;
    protected final View view;
    protected float perValue;

    public HeightAnimation(View view, int fromHeight, int toHeight) {
        this.view = view;
        this.originalHeight = fromHeight;
        this.perValue = (toHeight - fromHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (originalHeight + perValue
                * interpolatedTime);
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

in which the applyTransformation is giving me the remaining time or effect of progress call back but it solved my problem.